# How do I use onSubmit with actions that don't return a promise?

Tags: redux-form

From the documentation for onSubmit [1], it appears that to get the most out of redux-form (eg, update fields with error details, redirect on success), a promise should be returned.

If using redux-thunk or similar, and returning promises from action creators, this is ok.

However, the async actions in my app don't return promises - they use a middleware to handle API requests. Like the `callAPIMiddleware` function here in the redux docs [2].

When a form is submitted, I want to trigger a `SAVE` action, let the server do it's thing, and handle the response by listening for the `SAVE_SUCCESS` or `SAVE_ERROR` actions that are triggered automatically by the middleware. My form would then show errors, do something after success, etc.

Is there a way to do this or do I just need to return promises from my action creators?

[1] http://redux-form.com/6.0.5/docs/api/ReduxForm.md

[2] http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ReducingBoilerplate.html

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue. I'm using `Redux-Observable` to contain all my side-effects in RxJS epics. This means that my action creators do not return any promise either.

There is a workaround which consist into returning an empty Promise that will never resolve. This will make the form start the submit process. When you are complete, you can use an action creator to dispatch a `stopSubmit` action. This last action lets you define form errors and such.

However, there is currently a bug opened in the GitHub for that (https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/2591). There is a pull request to fix this bug (https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/pull/2731). Hopefully, it will be accepted soon.